# Xcode can not run Playground

Tags: xcode, swift-playground

Iam getting this error in console during execution code in Xcode playground. Can anyone help for to understand and solve it?

> Error encountered communicating with Xcode: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=61 "Connection refused"

Comment: Did you try to restart computer ?

Comment: @CZ54 Yes, this issue exists already several days. I also reinstalled Xcode but problem did not solve.

Comment: Do you get the same issue if you create a new playground?

Comment: @DávidPásztor yes, I created several playgrounds but there is not any result

Answer (score 0):

did you try to change platform settings to macOS its working for me